# Can jQuery detect if something has been returned false

Tags: jquery, validation, fadein

My predicament is that i have a piece of code that works fine in FF but not in IE. I'm submitting a form and validating it first with jQuery. The problem is that when i fadeIn() a message saying "fields required" its fadeIn() twice because there are two inputs to validate, so in FF this works fine, but in IE, it tries to fade in twice and actually the message appears then disappears straight away. SO what i thought i could do is say "if either returns false then fadeIn message" therefore only doing one fadeIn!

```
                var name = $("#name").val();
                var email = $("#email").val();
                if (name == ""){
                    $("#needed").fadeIn();
                    return false;   
                }
                if (email == ""){
                    $("#needed").fadeIn();
                    return false;
                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why don't you just

```
if (name == "" || email == ""){
      $("#needed").fadeIn();
      return false;
}
```

Comment: same result. no idea why! IE problem maybe?

Comment: how is your function attached to the form submit?

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
if (!name || !email) {
  var $n = $("#needed") ;
  if ($n.is(":visible")) $n.fadeOut(500); 
  $n.fadeIn (200);
  return false;
}
```